# How to merge fields from separate models/resources into a single resource in Laravel Nova ( V4 ) for e-commerce functionality?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm working on a Laravel project that requires e-commerce functionality, specifically managing products and their associated product items. I have two separate models and resources for products and product items.

Here's a simplified structure of my models and resources:

Product Model:

- Fields: id, name, description, etc.
- Resource: ProductResource

ProductItem Model:

- Fields: id, product_id, size, price, etc.
- Resource: ProductItemResource

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a single resource, namely ProductResource, where I can add a product along with its associated product items in a single form within the Nova administration panel.

I have already created the separate resources for both the product and product item models, and they work as expected. However, I'm struggling with merging the fields from the product item resource into the product resource.

I have tried different approaches, such as using nested forms, but I couldn't find a solution that allows me to combine the fields seamlessly and ensure proper data validation and persistence.

Can someone please guide me on how to merge the fields from these separate models/resources into a single resource in Laravel Nova for managing e-commerce products and their associated product items? It would be really helpful if you could provide an example or code snippet to illustrate the solution.

Thank you so much for your assistance!